# what's the difference between the two ways of writting in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

1,     `$.each(a,f);`

2,`$("a").each(f);`

i know the last line meaning, which represents all `<a>` elements in the document. Then call the each() method then invoke the function `f` once for each selected element. but i don't know what's the meaning of the first one? and what's the use of it? thank you.

Comment: Where did you see the first form used?

Comment: the first one is not implemented in jquery, at least i have never seen it, and don't see what's the use of it

Comment: @Flimzy: here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: have you even checked? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ and http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful, in your example `a` does not need to be the same type of object.

`$.each(array, function)` is for being used on normal arrays.

The idea behind `$(selector).each(function)` is the possibility to use the `each` "operator" on the result of a jQuery selector.

Here are the links to both ways of using `each`:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 0):

The first one iterates over something iterable, like an array or a jQuery object. It doesn't necessarily need to iterate over elements in the document, like the second one.

Answer (score 0):

The first syntax would generally be used for iterating over a JavaScript array.  You could use it with a jQuery object, but the second syntax would be more readable in that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 iterates any provided array.

Method 2 iterates over each provided selector in the DOM